# How can I use i in loop to make variance?

Tags: python

How can I change this code

```
train_0.append(0)
train_1.append(1)
train_2.append(2)
train_3.append(3)
```

using loop like under?

```
for i in range(4):
    train_i.append(i)
```

My code occurs this error.

```
NameError: name 'train_i' is not defined
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use dictionary.

Comment: What are you really trying to do with these trains?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provided that you have all `train_<i>` variables defined in global scope you could access them via `globals()`. [Demo](https://repl.it/repls/WorstWindyDesigns)

```
train_0 = []
train_1 = []
train_2 = []
train_3 = []


for i in range(4):
    globals()[f'train_{i}'].append(i)

print(train_0, train_1, train_2, train_3)
```

Comment: Better to add try .. except block to prevent crush in case if variable doesn't exist.

Comment: @OlvinRoght This would  swallow an actual error in code. :) So no. Fail early.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko It works^^. And I have one more question. I really need help at this point. Please look at under.

Comment: @woncheol You don't need `globals()` when you want to set instance properties. `setattr(self, f'data_{i}', value)` would suffice. https://repl.it/repls/LastingCavernousRuntimeenvironment

Answer (score 0):

There is some methods how to do this, but usually such as problems defines bad code... Better to do something with code and covert big amount of variables to something iterable.

There is some methods:

```
for i in range(4):
    train = globals().get("train_{}".format(i), None)
    if train:
        train.append(i)

for i in range(4):
    try:
        eval("train_{0}.append({0})".format(i))
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class, to define `self.variance`, how I can adjust your solution?

```
for i in range(4):
        globals()["test_{}".format(i)].append(ToTensor(vectors[i]))
```

Becuase upper code works with your help.

But under case (in class) it doesn't work.

```
class MyDataset():
    def __init__(self, cropped_img_vectors, targets):
        self.data_0 = cropped_img_vectors[0]
        self.data_1 = cropped_img_vectors[1]
        self.data_2 = cropped_img_vectors[2]
        self.data_3 = cropped_img_vectors[3]
        self.targets = targets

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        data_0 = self.data_0[index]
        data_1 = self.data_1[index]
        data_2 = self.data_2[index]
        data_3 = self.data_3[index]
        y = self.targets[index]
        dataset = []
        for i in range(4):
            dataset.append(["data_{}".format(i)])
        return dataset, y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_0)
```

I changed uppder to under.

```
class MyDataset():
    def __init__(self, cropped_1pixel_dataset, targets):
        for i in range(4):
            globals()["self.data_{}".format(i)] = cropped_1pixel_dataset[i]
        self.targets = targets

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        for i in range(4):
            globals()["data_{}".format(i)] = cropped_1pixel_dataset[i][index]
        y = self.targets[index]
        return [globals()["data_{}".format(i)] for i in range(4)], y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_0)
```

And after run this cell,

```
MyDataset(train_cropped_1pixel_dataset, train_dataset.targets)
```

it occur this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-960ee70394c1> in <module>
      3 train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset,
      4                                            batch_size = batch_size,
----> 5                                            shuffle = True)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, sampler, batch_sampler, num_workers, collate_fn, pin_memory, drop_last, timeout, worker_init_fn)
    800             if sampler is None:
    801                 if shuffle:
--> 802                     sampler = RandomSampler(dataset)
    803                 else:
    804                     sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __init__(self, data_source, replacement, num_samples)
     58 
     59         if self.num_samples is None:
---> 60             self.num_samples = len(self.data_source)
     61 
     62         if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:

<ipython-input-10-293dc919d173> in __len__(self)
     12 
     13     def __len__(self):
---> 14         return len(self.data_0)

AttributeError: 'MyDataset' object has no attribute 'data_0'
```

I really need helps..
Thank you.