# Python loop to call different variables

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am trying to create loop in Python to call different variables.

```py
example0="result1"
example1="result2"
example2="result3"
example3="result4"
example4="result5"


for i in range(5):
    print(example+(i))
```

The result I expect will be

```
result1
result2
result3
result4
result5
```

I have tried several solutions, the furthest I got is with :

```py
for i in range(5):
    locals()["example"+str(i)]()
```

but I recieve error

```py
"    locals()["example"+str(i)]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949845/10824407) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55933230/10824407) answers where I've already explain how you can do this and why you should avoid this.

Comment: Unless you have a very specific usage case where you need to access `locals()` directly and cannot create a list or a dictionary instead, it would be advisable to use a list or a dict. It does not seem like you have such a usage case. This is what containers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would be a way to go:

```
example0="result1"
example1="result2"
example2="result3"
example3="result4"
example4="result5"


for i in range(5):
    print(locals()["example"+str(i)])
```

Output:

```
result1
result2
result3
result4
result5
```

Answer (score 0):

With the last parentheses you are considering that the variable called result followed by the number you touch is a function. And he must call her. Remove those parentheses. For example:

```
for i in range(5):
  print locals()["example"+str(i)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the aswer, however I recieved syntax error:                   print locals()["example"+str(i)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you inside a function, aren't? If you don't have called a function you have to replace locals for globals

Comment: I found the reason for that, when I copied your solution, print statement was not inside "for" loop

Answer (score -1):

try using "str". It may work :)  .